# How do I fill in days of the week between two days

Tags: python

I have a list like `['Monday', 'Thursday']` with two days of the week. I want to be able to retrieve a list of days of the week between these two -> `['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday']`

1. I am happy to write a custom function in Python to do this. But wondering if there is an easier way that I might be missing.
2. How can I retrieve the day index for a given day of the week (day of the week name - example:'Wednesday') in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve a list of days of the week between two given days, you can use below function:

```
def days_between(start_day, end_day):
    days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    start_index = days.index(start_day)
    end_index = days.index(end_day)
        
    if start_index <= end_index:
        return days[start_index:end_index+1]
    else:
        return days[start_index:] + days[:end_index+1]
    
# Example usage
start_day = 'Monday'
end_day = 'Thursday'
result = days_between(start_day, end_day)
print(result)
```